# Configure simple_token_authentication with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After setup devise and simple_token_authentication and configure the

**ApplicationController**

```
 acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
  respond_to :html, :json
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  #added username to signup
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:name, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs

  end


#Override authenticate_user! to handle html and json separately
def authenticate_user!
    if self.request.format.html?
      super
    elsif self.request.format.json?
      if self.request.parameters["controller"].start_with?("devise")
        # use the default if session related
        super
      else
        # others
        if user_signed_in?
          # use the default if already signed in
          super
        else

          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When click on the User Edit Profile shows:

> ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#edit wrong number of
>   arguments (given 1, expected 0) Extracted source (around line #20):

the error points to authenticate_user!

```
def authenticate_user!
    if self.request.format.html?
      super
    elsif self.request.format.json?
```

in this case cant Override the authenticate_user!? 
Or this is related with rails 5.1?

Someone is having this issue with  simple_token_authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Devise defines a method named `authenticate_user!`, which takes one argument.  You are overriding the method, but your method doesn't take any arguments.  At some point, Devise makes the call `authenticate_user!(some_arg_here)`, so you get the error explanation:

```
                         Called with one arg...
                            |
                            V
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
                                       ^
                                       |
                             ...but the method def expects 0 args
```

Here's a simple example of your error:

```
class Dog
  def bark
    puts "wuff"
  end
end

Dog.new.bark(3)

--output:--
1.rb:2:in `bark': wrong number of arguments 
(given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Here's the fix:

```
class Dog
  def bark(repeat)
    puts (["wuff"]*repeat).join(", ")
  end
end

Dog.new.bark(3)

--output:--
wuff, wuff, wuff
```

So you need to define your `authenticate_user!` method so that it takes one argument.  If you don't care about the argument, then name it `trash`.

Comment: 7stud thank you. but that is the point i did not passed any argument!
and the method is complaining to expected 0 arguments

Comment: so i still did not understand.

Comment: @lula, *i did not passed any argument*--Where are *you* calling `authenticate_user!`?

Comment: in this case to check if the user signed_in to edit the user profile page


 <% if user_signed_in? %>
             Logged in as <strong><%= link_to(current_user.username,user_path(current_user)) %></strong>.
             <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %>

Comment: so this happens when click on the edit_user_registration_path